# letter counting

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script counting the different letters I type, but either I get an error "too many hotkeys" (recursive calling my self I guess) or the key I enter isn't shown.

This gives no letters

```
a::  
a_cnt += 1  
return  

b::  
b_cnt += 1  
return
```

This gives too many hotkeys

```
a::  
a_cnt += 1  
send a  
return  

b::  
b_cnt += 1  
send b  
return
```

Answer (score 2):

Try starting with a `$`, e.g.

```
$a::
a_cnt += 1
send a
return
```

The [$ prefix](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) prevents a command from triggering itself from a `Send`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ~before a hotkey, the key will be forwarded to the application AND the commands will be executed. This will make it into one-liners instead of multiple line commands.

```
~a::a_cnt += 1 ; Lowercase a
~+a::aa_cnt += 1 ; Uppercase a

^a::MsgBox, %a_cnt%
^+a::MsgBox, %aa_cnt%
```